# Crop & Edit Images in C#

Tags: c#, resize, zooming, rotation, crop

I am looking to make a tool that allows me to basically edit images as you could in MS Paint. I can currently draw shapes and pens on my image but i don't know how to: 
 - Crop
 - Save New Image with Bitmap
 - Zoom in & Out on Image
 - Stretch Image Out
 - Rotate the Image
If anyone could help with any part of this question it would be most appreciated, and i have put this all in one question to stop me posting multiple similar questions.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing) with all you need.

Rotation sample [here.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/rotateimage.aspx)

If you use WPF [check this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx).